# awk - keep only lines in file that start with the same characters in certain column

Tags: awk

I have a file with around 1000 lines of data that looks like this

```
ZIPCODE;STREETNAME;NAME;MAIL-ADDRESS  
12345;Mainstreet 1;Anton;anton@gmail.com  
23456;First Street 3;Mike;mike@yahoo.com
12345;Mainstreet 15;Tom;tom@hotmail.com
63434;Second Street 23;Anna;anna@mail.com
23456;First Street 74;Patrick;patrick@hotmail.com
32753;Third Street 28;Alex;alex@gmail.com
```

In this case I want to identify (and keep only) the lines where the first 6 characters of the street name match at least one other line.

The desired output should look like this (keeping only the lines where the first 6 letters of column 2 are the same as some other line(s))

```
12345;Mainstreet 1;Anton;anton@gmail.com  
23456;First Street 3;Mike;mike@yahoo.com
12345;Mainstreet 15;Tom;tom@hotmail.com (<- same street as #1)
23456;First Street 74;Patrick;patrick@hotmail.com (<- same street as #2)
```

I figured out how to just keep the lines with the same FULL street name (column 2) using awk

`awk -F';' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} { c[$2]++; l[$2,c[$2]]=$0 } END { for (i in c) { if (c[i] > 1) for (j = 1; j <= c[i]; j++) print l[i,j] } }' FILE`

I also know that there is a function for substrings ( substr(s,index,len) ) in awk but I can't figure out how to change the above mentioned code to just use the first 6 letters of column 2.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to discard single mentions of a street name?
Modify your command like this:

```
awk -F';' '
BEGIN {OFS = FS} 
{ pfx=substr($2,1,6); c[pfx]++; l[pfx,c[pfx]]=$0 } 
END { for (i in c) { if (c[i] > 1) for (j = 1; j <= c[i]; j++) print l[i,j] } }' FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is a bit convoluted, but commented it may help. What you want to do is store records in an array, and then store the count of times the first 6-character substring is seen. Then in the `END` rule, loop over the substrings and for those with a count greater than one, loop printing the records where the first 6-characters of field 2 match the substring, e.g.

With your data in a file named `streets`, you would have:

```
awk -F';' '{
    recs[$2]=$0             # save records keyed by 2nd field
    ss[substr($2,1,6)]++    # save count of substr of 6 chars from 2nd field
}
END {
    for (i in ss)                           # loop saved substrings
        if (ss[i] > 1)                      # if count > 1
            for (j in recs)                 # loop stored records
                if (substr(j,1,6) == i)     # if 1st 6 chars match substring
                    print recs[j]           # print record
}' streets
23456;First Street 74;Patrick;patrick@hotmail.com
23456;First Street 3;Mike;mike@yahoo.com
12345;Mainstreet 15;Tom;tom@hotmail.com
12345;Mainstreet 1;Anton;anton@gmail.com
```

Let me know if you have questions. Looks like @user727089 may have a tad bit cleaner logic.

Answer (score 0):

a double scan approach will be trivial

```
$ awk -F\; '{k=substr($2,1,6)} 
     NR==FNR{a[k]++; next} 
     a[k]>1' file{,}

12345;Mainstreet 1;Anton;anton@gmail.com
23456;First Street 3;Mike;mike@yahoo.com
12345;Mainstreet 15;Tom;tom@hotmail.com
23456;First Street 74;Patrick;patrick@hotmail.com
```